# List body sensors available on Android devices

Tags: sensors

How can I list body sensors available on Android devices?

Comment: Think of any possible sensor, it's available. That's because Android uses the Linux kernel, meaning it possible to utilize any sensor out there. That might require a custom kernel, but it works.

Comment: Cool, but I was just wondering about buil-in body sensors available so far. For instance I know there is one that can measure your pulse. What other bio sensors are there?

Comment: There are a lot, from step sensors and counters to anything. If you look at the data sheets of some phones and tablets, you will see a lot of different sensors. Feel free to make a community wiki answer and add as many as you can find.

Comment: Please note that we cannot give you a list on "all sensors that might be available on the thousands of possible Android devices". This site is for end-users, not for "scientific research issues". To interpret it as an end-user question, for my answer I "rephrased it in my mind" to match: "How can I find out what sensors are available on my Android device".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ADB can be your friend here:

```
adb shell dumpsys sensorservice
```

will provide you with a list of all your devices sensors plus details on them. In the following example, I've just captured a list of their names (better readability) using my Linux machine with my *Wileyfox Swift* connected:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys sensorservice |egrep -B99999 "^halVersion" |awk -F '|' '{print $1}' |grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$'
Sensor List:
liteon-light   
liteon-proximity
BOSCH Acceleration Sensor
BOSCH Gyroscope Sensor
BOSCH Magnetic Field Sensor
BOSCH Orientation Sensor
BOSCH Gravity Sensor
BOSCH Linear Acceleration Sensor
BOSCH Rotation Vector Sensor
BOSCH Game Rotation Vector Sensor
BOSCH Gyroscope Uncalibrated Sensor
BOSCH Magnetic Field Uncalibrated Sensor
BOSCH Geomagnetic Rotation Vector Sensor
Rotation Vector Sensor
Gravity Sensor 
Linear Acceleration Sensor
Orientation Sensor
Corrected Gyroscope Sensor
Gyroscope Bias (debug)
9-axis fusion disabled (0 clients), gyro-rate= 200.00Hz, q=< 0, 0, 0, 0 > (0), b=< 0, 0, 0 >
halVersion 16973825
```

Distinguishing the sensor types is a different issue and IMHO not covered that easily. But knowing what sensors are there altogether, you can tell them apart yourself.

Self-promotion: My tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) includes those in the device documentation it generates.